# Json Deserialize C# Class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Im new to Json and so i need your help to deserialize something.
I have a httpclient sending a webrequest:

```
  HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(JsonBaseuri + IDInput.Text.ToString());
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            InventoryJsonData.RootObject root1 = new InventoryJsonData.RootObject();
            root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InventoryJsonData.RootObject>(content);
```

The RootClass is defined as:

```
class InventoryJsonData
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public object Error { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I get an error and i dont know if my code is right for what i want to do. I want to get a root1 object with the Attributes from the Json data from the webrequest. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Can you include the exception you are getting?

Comment: Also include the value that gets populated into the `content` variable please.

Comment: Just like JonEgerton and  pwee167 posted - you need attach more details.
Another thing is that you don't have to create `RootObject` before deserialization. `InventoryJsonData.RootObject root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InventoryJsonData.RootObject>(content);` is enought

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies.  @JonEgerton

Comment: Post your sample json into http://www.csharp2json.com and check you've declared your class correctly.

Comment: I have done my class by using csharp2json.com ... @KaelanFouwels

Comment: Example Response: {"Success":true,"Error":null,"Price":11.05715530,"Username":"76561198171429346", and so on ... Im just interested in the price value ...

Comment: Similar exception occur when use VS2015 and Newtonsoft.Json 7.0 version. If you use version 7 of serializer maybe just try downgrad it to v6

Comment: @PiotrPasieka Did you test it with v6 in vs 2015?

Comment: No I don't have VS2015. I just searched for possible cause with criteria: newtonsoft.json and exception you posted. There are few posts on the internet with similar error. If your project is under version control then downgrade is quick operation. Open nuget console. install desired version of dll and if it still not working then just revert changes and  we will try something else :)

Comment: @PiotrPasieka Ok thank you, i thought i did a mistake in coding, i will downgrade json later and write the result ...

Comment: @PiotrPasieka Its working thank you again for your great help - If you create an answer i can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar exception occur when use VS2015 and Newtonsoft.Json 7.0 version. If you use version 7 of serializer maybe just try downgrade it to v6. Use nuget to change version